# Page displays formula rather than result (but for only ONE of the cases)

Tags: javascript

I'm a student currently learning JavaScript. As practice, I wanted to make a cute reading randomizer for a friend with a simple form and a if else input validation process.
Both of my first two cases function as I expect them two, but the third, the one that actually does the calculation, does not send the result of the calculation to be displayed, but rather the formula. I'm not sure where I went wrong.

```js
function pickfic() {
  // Get the value of the input fields
  let minNumChosen = document.getElementById('minNum').value;
  let maxNumChosen = document.getElementById('maxNum').value;
  
  // If input Not a Number or min bigger than max
  let reply;
  if (isNaN(minNumChosen) || isNaN(maxNumChosen) || minNumChosen > maxNumChosen ) {
    reply = "I think you pissed off my sandwich. Also, those numbers make no sense to me.";
  } 
    // If min is zero
  else if (minNumChosen == 0) {
   reply = "Really, dude? You have an Excel line for 'zero'?? Witch.";
  }
  else {
    // if range is correct, randomize number
    const generateRandomNumber = (minNumChosen, maxNumChosen) =>  {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
      };
    reply = "Today, you should read fic number " + generateRandomNumber + "!";
  }
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = reply;
}
```

For the last case, the page displays : "Today, you should read fic number (minNumChosen, maxNumChosen) => { return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min); }!"

You can find the codepen [here](https://codepen.io/alice-g/pen/LYQVoEM?editors=0010).

EDIT: Turns out I found another bug, which is probably logic based. It seems that for my function, 2 is greater than 10. So it must be judging by the first digit...

Comment: you forgot the brackets on the function name which is required to invoke it generateRandomNumber()

Without that I guess your function was coerced to a string since its being concatenated to string

Comment: Try checking the console on code pen, it tells you what the errors are - and then google the errors -

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function pickfic() {
  // Get the value of the input fields
  let minNumChosen = document.getElementById('minNum').value;
  let maxNumChosen = document.getElementById('maxNum').value;
  
  // If input Not a Number or min bigger than max
  let reply;
  if (isNaN(minNumChosen) || isNaN(maxNumChosen) || minNumChosen > maxNumChosen ) {
    reply = "I think you pissed off my sandwich. Also, those numbers make no sense to me.";
  }
    // If min is zero
  else if (minNumChosen == 0) {
   reply = "Really, dude? You have an Excel line for 'zero'?? Witch.";
  }
  else {
    // if range is correct, randomize number
    const generateRandomNumber = (min, max) =>  {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
      };
    reply = "Today, you should read fic number " + generateRandomNumber(parseInt(minNumChosen), parseInt(maxNumChosen)) + "!";
  }
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = reply;
}
```

```html
<input id="minNum" placeholder="min">
<input id="maxNum" placeholder="max">
<div id="result"></div>
<button onclick=pickfic()>Click</button>
```

You had to add parenthesis to generateRandomNumber()

And also make the minNumChosen and maxNumChosen into integers with parseInt().

There was also another mistake where you didn't name the parameters of your generateRandomNumber function (min, max).

Comment: Thank you! It made the code work!
Now it just seems to only use the first digit for comparison because... 20 is smaller than 5...

Answer (score 0):

```
function pickfic() {
  // Get the value of the input fields
  let minNumChosen = document.getElementById('minNum').value;
  let maxNumChosen = document.getElementById('maxNum').value;
  
  // If input Not a Number or min bigger than max
  let reply;
  if (isNaN(minNumChosen) || isNaN(maxNumChosen) || minNumChosen > maxNumChosen ) {
    reply = "I think you pissed off my sandwich. Also, those numbers make no sense to me.";
  } 
    // If min is zero
  else if (minNumChosen == 0) {
   reply = "Really, dude? You have an Excel line for 'zero'?? Witch.";
  }
  else {
    // if range is correct, randomize number
    const generateRandomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxNumChosen  - minNumChosen) + minNumChosen);
    reply = "Today, you should read fic number " + generateRandomNumber + "!";
  }
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = reply;
```

OR

You created a function which takes in values but you didn't provide the min and max value while calling the generateRandomNumber function

```
function pickfic() {
  // Get the value of the input fields
  let minNumChosen = document.getElementById('minNum').value;
  let maxNumChosen = document.getElementById('maxNum').value;
  
  // If input Not a Number or min bigger than max
  let reply;
  if (isNaN(minNumChosen) || isNaN(maxNumChosen) || minNumChosen > maxNumChosen ) {
    reply = "I think you pissed off my sandwich. Also, those numbers make no sense to me.";
  } 
    // If min is zero
  else if (minNumChosen == 0) {
   reply = "Really, dude? You have an Excel line for 'zero'?? Witch.";
  }
  else {
    // if range is correct, randomize number
    const generateRandomNumber = (min,max) =>  {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
      };
    reply = "Today, you should read fic number " + generateRandomNumber(minNumChosen, maxNumChosen) + "!";
  }
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = reply;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I haven't caught that I hadn't used minNumChosen in all the formula. So I did that. Now, if I use generateRandomNumber(), it just says "Today, you should read fic number NaN!". If I used generateRandomNumber as a variable name, it displays the formula.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the last bug thanks to @SchokokuchenBäcker's input on the first issue.
My conditional was comparing strings, which is why 20 was smaller than 5 !
Writing the first conditional like this:

```
if (isNaN(minNumChosen) || isNaN(maxNumChosen) || parseInt(minNumChosen) >= parseInt(maxNumChosen) )
```

makes it functional!